is it possible to autofilter data set/field without a header?
I would like to autofilter a data set/field that doesn't have a header
doubt there is a parameter option but thought I would ask
tried .header = no
chatty because I need 220 characters
hope I am not violating forum rules.

AFAIK it is not possible to filter data that does not have any headers - even manually. Excel will simply choose the first value as the "header". So one way around the problem would be to add a dummy header to the right of your data - but that won't work if you don't have a blank line before your data.
Another option is to convert the data to a "table" - which will generate a header for you (as well as an autofilter)

thank you.  answer is appreciated and sufficient

You could use VBA to loop over your data, checking the content of the column you want to filter and decide row by row if you want to show or hide the row.
Const FilterCol As Long = 2  ' Set to the column number you want to filter
Const LookFor = "Your long search string"

Dim row As Range
For Each row In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
    row.EntireRow.Hidden = Not (row.Cells(1, FilterCol) Like "*" & LookFor & "*")
Next row

If your search should be flexible (different columns, different search terms), you need to think about the user interface. A simple routine could look like this.
Sub filterMyData()   
    Dim filterCol As Long
    Dim LookFor As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error GoTo filterMyData_Exit  ' Ensure that screen updating is enabled
    
    filterCol = ActiveCell.Column
    LookFor = InputBox("Please enter the search string:", "Filter your data")
    
    Dim row As Range
    For Each row In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
        row.EntireRow.Hidden = Not (row.Cells(1, filterCol) Like "*" & LookFor & "*")
    Next row

filterMyData_Exit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Note that the routine disables screen update to avoid flickering.
You could assign the routine to a shortcut (like "Shift+Ctrl+F")
